# How to bring methods from a module into the scope of the caller of a method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ffi, rust, ruby-ffi

The code should look like this:

```
def bring_into_scope(module)
  #here the caller of the method should get methods from +module+
end

class Bar
  def bar_method
    #do stuff
  end
end

class Foo
  def initialize(bar)
    bring_into_scope(bar)

    bar_method
  end
end
```

I need the functinality because I want to write a library that inlines rust code, so one should be able to write:

```
class RustAndRuby
  def ruby_method; end

  #this should make all fn's in the rust code available in RustAndRuby
  Rust.code {
    "String with rust code..."
  }
end
```

Is this possible in ruby?
(If you need further information feel free to ask!)

Comment: So what is rust, a class or module. Where is it ?

Comment: Rust is a programming language. http://rust-lang.org

Comment: Rust code needs to be compiled, so `Rust#code` would need to pass the string on to a rust compiler, and that's just the first problem. Next you'll have a binary you need to link the functions to. I've never done this personally, but I know it's possible though unlikely easy. Or, you could write a rust interpreter in Ruby, and then just call that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at [this](https://github.com/brson/rubyrustdemo), written by one of the main contributors of Rust.